# multiply two different dataframes based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df1:

```
year   rate 
2022   1.000
2023   1.015
2024   1.049
2025   1.084
2026   1.121
2027   1.158
2028   1.197
2029   1.237
2030   1.278
2031   1.321
2032   1.365
```

and df2:

```
Name   value  code  portion
A       10     1      2
B       12     2      0
```

My request is:

```
Name   value  code  portion       2022              2023           .....     2032
A       10     1      2       1.000*(10-2)+2     1.015*(10-2)+2           1.365*(10-2)+2 
B       12     2      0        12                     12                    12
C       20     1      6       1.000*(20-6)+6     1.015*(20-6)+6           1.365*(20-6)+6
D       8      2      0        8                     8                       8
```

I tried with `.loc` but I failed

My trial is

```
df_multiply=df2['value'].apply(lambda x: x * df1['rate'])
```

Comment: can you write your dataframes and the request in a table. It looks very messy hence hard to understand.

Comment: df2 includes C and D rows , I forgot  to add them

Comment: To calculate `1.000*(10-2)+2` for `2022` are you using this formula `rate_in_2022 * (value-portion)+portion` if portion is not 0 else `value`?

Comment: Please, Cool Breeze, Could you provide that formula in pythonic way using apply function

Comment: I've written that in the answer, try that. Using lambda in such calculation will be very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the calculation with numpy broadcasting and the conditionally change the rows that doesn't need calculation.

```py
df2[df1['year']] = (df2['value'].sub(df2['portion']).to_numpy() * (df1['rate'].to_numpy()[:, None]) + df2['portion'].to_numpy()[None, :]).T
df2.loc[~df2['Name'].isin(['A', 'C']), df1['year']] = df2['value']
```

```
print(df2)

  Name  value  code  portion  2022   2023    2024    2025    2026    2027    2028    2029    2030    2031   2032
0    A     10     1        2  10.0  10.12  10.392  10.672  10.968  11.264  11.576  11.896  12.224  12.568  12.92
1    B     12     2        0  12.0  12.00  12.000  12.000  12.000  12.000  12.000  12.000  12.000  12.000  12.00
2    C     20     1        6  20.0  20.21  20.686  21.176  21.694  22.212  22.758  23.318  23.892  24.494  25.11
3    D      8     2        0   8.0   8.00   8.000   8.000   8.000   8.000   8.000   8.000   8.000   8.000   8.00
```

Comment: df2 includes multiple rows looks like above-mentioned rows so could you update the following df2.loc[~df2['Name'].isin(['A', 'C']), df1['year']] = df2['value']

Comment: @sazaki I don't know the logic how you determine which Name you want to keep which name you want to calculate with rate, you can implement your logic to replace `~df2['Name'].isin(['A', 'C'])`.

Comment: I implement  df2.loc[~df2['Code']==2, df1['year']] = df2['value'] but the result as I want

Comment: Thanks ,Ynjxsjmh , I implement df2.loc[df2['Code']==2, df1['year']] = df2['value'] without "~" and I get what I want

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
# Calculating the value
df2[df1['year']] = ((df2['value'] - df2['portion'] if df2['portion'] else df2['value']) * df1['rate']) + df2['portion']

df2.loc[~df2['Name'].isin(['A', 'C']), df1['year']] = df2['value']
```

Comment: df1 doesn't include column portion , do you mean df2?

Comment: yes, i've updated the above code.

Comment: I got the following error  ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: I think, you've got the result from the other posted solution.